# Duda con constructores por defecto en c++

Tags: c++, constructor

Tengo entendido que al hacer una clase sin constructores el compilador los añade por defecto (el de copia, el vacío y el de movimiento) y que cuando definimos un constructor, los que vienen por defecto ya no se añaden, el caso es que he creado una clase con constructor parametrizado y si puedo llamar al constructor vacío por defecto:

```
class MiClase{
    std::map<std::string,std::string> map_;
public:
    MiClase(const std::map<std::string,std::string> &map){
        map_ = map;
    }
};

int main(){
    MiClase objeto(); // llamada al constructor vacio de MiClase

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estás llamando al constructor, estás declarando una función llamada `objeto` que devuelve una instancia de `MiClase` y que no recibe parámetros:

```
int main(){
    MiClase objeto();

    int status;
    char *const realname = abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(objeto).name(), 0, 0, &status);
    std::cout << realname;
    free(realname);

    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior  [genera `MiClase ()` como salida](https://tio.run/##hZDPasMwDMbP1lMYBsUZXenZSXPZec8QHEdrPRLb@A9kjDx7Jifd1tvAYH2Svp8sa@9f9KjsdV2fjNVjHpA3k/It/EnjYgqopsecnmfVm9OtBSB7jPzNvNKNX8BiGqQkRLMFZDX2enyIW07Frgaf@9FoCexuFdrZmPj/9gNVKxrECodfCq4GtsBSAxibSBsrSsMdzF3/gcmJiuqsNMSkUo7k0TcV@PM@lzYcrZqQgLSZlF2nZ9UNONHnjCjSp0cziB1VnUqnqI78vJ3DTqQB@/ba5cSb5pdJ@feAKH709pKAKQfLzzUs6/oN).

Si quieres llamar al constructor en ese caso, usa llaves o no uses paréntesis... y te fallará al compilar:

```
int main(){
    MiClase objeto1{}; // Error: no existe constructor que no reciba parámetros.
    MiClase objeto2;   // Error: no existe constructor que no reciba parámetros.

    return 0;
}
```